# Возврат в меню пайтон

Tags: python

Я начинающий питонист и написал такое начало для моего большого проэкта. Это программа работы со временем. Таймер и секундомер. И мне нужно чтобы после окончания выполнения кода меня вернуло назад. То-есть кинуло в меню выбора между таймером и секундомером. Пожалуйста , подскажите как это сделать.

```
import time
import sys
from termcolor import colored
import pyttsx3
Print('1-таймер, 2-секундомер')

mode=float(input())
mode=mode * 1
if 1>=mode:
    print('о чем напомнить?')
    text=str(input())
    print('через сколько?(указывать в секундах)')
    local_sec = float(input())
    local_sec=local_sec*1
    local_min=local_sec // 60
    if 59>= local_sec:
        if 1>=local_sec:
            print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_sec)+' секунду')
        if 2>4 >=local_sec:
            print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_sec)+' секунды')
        if 5<=local_sec:
            print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_sec)+' секунд')
        time.sleep(local_sec)
        print(text)
   if 60<=local_sec:
        local_min=local_sec // 60
        if 1>=local_min:
            print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_min)+' минуту')
        if 2>4>local_min:
            print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_min)+' минуты')
        if 5<=local_min:
            print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_min)+' минут')
        time.sleep(local_sec)
        print(text)


if 2<=mode:
    sec = 0
while True:
    print(sec)
    time.sleep(1)
    sec += 1
    if 60 <= sec:
        sys.exit()
```

Comment: Использовать функции, выбор одной функцией, а таймер и секундомер другими, и в конце ф-ий таймера или секундомера вызывать ф-ию выбора

Comment: Программу можно разбить на 3 функции. 1й выбор,2й секундомер, 3й таймер. В конце можно бесконечный цикл с вызовом первой функции (пока ответ не придёт она и будет ждать.ответ придёт,сразу вызовет 1ю). Для сравнения используй == mode

Answer (score 0):

В питоне нет поддержки goto, но если вы так хотите его использовать, воспользуйтесь этой библиотекой https://github.com/snoack/python-goto

Я вам крайне не рекомендую использовать это, а воспользоваться бесконечным циклом.

```
import time
import sys
from termcolor import colored
import pyttsx3
Print('1-таймер, 2-секундомер')

mode=float(input())
while mode!= -1 #-1 код выхода. 
 mode=mode * 1
 if 1>=mode:
     print('о чем напомнить?')
     text=str(input())
     print('через сколько?(указывать в секундах)')
     local_sec = float(input())
     local_sec=local_sec*1
     local_min=local_sec // 60
     if 59>= local_sec:
         if 1>=local_sec:
             print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_sec)+' секунду')
         if 2>4 >=local_sec:
             print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_sec)+' секунды')
         if 5<=local_sec:
             print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_sec)+' секунд')
         time.sleep(local_sec)
         print(text)
    if 60<=local_sec:
         local_min=local_sec // 60
         if 1>=local_min:
             print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_min)+' минуту')
         if 2>4>local_min:
             print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_min)+' минуты')
         if 5<=local_min:
             print('таймер установлен на '+str(local_min)+' минут')
         time.sleep(local_sec)
         print(text)


 if 2<=mode:
     sec = 0
 while True:
     print(sec)
     time.sleep(1)
     sec += 1
     if 60 <= sec:
         sys.exit()
 mode=float(input())
```

Таким образом программа будет работать вечно, пока пользователь не напишет код -1. Тогда она выйдет из цикла.

Comment: Я почти закончил код но появилась проблема:создал 2 переменную с таким же значением как у mode и мне нужно чтобы по окончании всех скриптов меня кидвло в меню выбора команд